# Get attribute from using dropdown yes no

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, custom-options

I have created a dropdown attribute with the options of "yes" and "no" with the hope to show an element with yes is selected in the admin. I have a few of these dropdown attributes that all show different icons depending if the product needs them. Unfortunately I can not get it to work. Here is my code.

```
<ul class="safety-footwear-icons">
<?php if($product->getAttributeText('safety_basic')=='yes'){ ?>
    <li class="sb">
        <span class="tooltiptext">SAFETY BASIC - EN ISO 20345:2011 + 200 joules toe protection</span>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement into some more details

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I'm trying to get the output form a dropdown attribute with the options of yes or no. If yes, then it will show the li with the span if no it will show nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do code like this :

```
<ul class="safety-footwear-icons">
<?php if($product->getSafetyBasic()){ ?>
    <li class="sb">
        <span class="tooltiptext">SAFETY BASIC - EN ISO 20345:2011 + 200 joules toe protection</span>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

**NOTE:** Just confirm product object is load before above code.

Comment: Thank you, big help